# When ever I try to put my turtlebot2(simulated in gazebo) into a namespace the fake laser stops publishing messages on /scan

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, namespaces, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to put multiple turtlebots in my simulation and need to declare group namespaces for this purpose. When defined within the namespace the robot_state_publisher published all the transforms under the new namespace but the fake laser first of all does not follow the namespace the /scan topic remains /scan and 2nd it even stops getting any message at /scan which is working fine without the group namespace declared. Below is my launch file

I want my /scan topic to be published under /robot1/scan so that I could add in multiple robots all publishing their own scans.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216611/when-ever-i-try-to-put-my-turtlebot2(simulated-in-gazebo)-into-a-namespace-the-fake-laser-stops-publishing-messages-on-/scan/) by [Usman Arif](https://answers.ros.org/users/22287/usman-arif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is remapping rule in laserscan_nodelet_manager.

You may want to remove this.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2015-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1